# Why are vibrations so common?

Tags: classical-mechanics, oscillators, vibrations

Why are vibrations so common? We all know, or pretend to know, that symmetries and the least action principle lead to conservation laws.Is there something more fundamental behind the fact that vibrations are everywhere?
My question is not about quantum mechanics or the microscopic world. I have in mind ripples in pools of water, the propagation of sound and so on.

Comment: Are you referring to the classical vibration of atoms?

Comment: The question is so vague it's hard to see how to answer it. Vibrations are so common because systems where the force is dependant on the displacement are so common. This in turn is because the EM force is inverse square.

Comment: @lemon I refer to the vibrations of atoms and the vibrations  that per example make a sound or a waves in a lake as well

Comment: @JohnRennie So vibrations are common because fields weaken with inverse square ( because the world is three- dimensional?)

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: @JohnRennie, please don't provide answers in the comment section.

Comment: @Mew: that wasn't an answer, it was a vaguely worded explanation of why the question is too vague to be answered. As such it is entirely reasonable to post it as a comment and the two likes (and counting) that my comment attracted suggest that others agree with me.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I liked your comment but I thought the displacement dependent force idea was a good answer to the question.

Comment: Vibrations are common because quadratic potentials approximate well minima of any smooth function. Surely this has  been asked before...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Write an answer